# JOIN Between entities of two models in Entity Framework

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

I have two tables located in two separated Entity Framework models and I would like to retrieve data making a JOIN between the two tables. I am using Entity Framework 3.1.

Is it possible to retrieve the information doing a JOIN between the two tables?

If yes, Should I use "LINQ to Entities" or "Entity SQL"?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, EF will not do it. You cannot create a single expression with entities from more than 1 domain. It will fail when you request the first item of the result.

Answer (score 0):

An Entity Framework model is a mapping between a database (store) model and a class model. Currently (if ever) one EF model can not read the mapping info an another model. So it won't be able to map an alien class to a table, let alone create SQL involving that table. As far as EF is concerned, the tables could be in two totally different data bases.

Alternatives:

- use linq-to-objects to join pre-fetched data from the two models, i.e. data fetched into memory by e.g. `ToList()`.
- Gather a list of values from one model and use it to get data from the other model (e.g. a list of `OrderId`s to be used in a `Contains` statement that gets `Orderline`s from the other model - unrealistic example, OK).
- Use only one EF model mapping to both (and more) tables.

Answer (score -1):

You have probably figured this out by now but here is my solution:

```
var data = db.FirstEntity
           .Join(db.SecondEntity, ent1 => ent1.ID, ent2 => ent2.ForeignKeyID,
           (ent1, ent2) => new { LeftSideObject = ent1, RightSideObject = ent2 }) 
           .Select(x => x.LeftSideObject);
```

I have named the variables as generically as I can, hopefully it makes sense!

Comment: Question is about distinct models, not just distinct entities. And with entities, you can use a navigation property instead of a join.